# Configure IIS 6.0 to serve all file extensions, even unknown ones

Tags: iis-6

I have a problem with IIS: if I ask an unknown file extension, such as .flv, it doesn't serve it and displays "page not found".
I can configure it in the Mime Types, but I want to be able to specify a wildcard, like in IIS 7, where I can allow all types under "Request Filtering".

Is it possible?
Thanks!

Comment: This question should be transfered to Serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already tried using an asterisk (*) in the Extension box for a new MIME type?

Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326965

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick (extension: .*, mime type: application/octet-stream)